# Subclass TSwitch in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, subclass, firemonkey

I have done a very simply subclass of the TSwitch that will not respond to mouse clicks or even allow setting IsChecked at runtime. I have not created this as a component so its only runtime constructed. It works if I create a TSwitch at runtime but will not work if its my subclassed switch.

```
TLayoutSwitch = class(TCustomSwitch, ILayoutBaseControl)
```

The issue appears to be in `SendMessage` called by `TSwitchModel.SetValue`. In `TMessageSender.SendMessage`. I cannot figure out how `TSwitchModel` is constructed so that the `Receiver` object is set.

RAD Studio 10 Seattle

```
TLayoutSwitch = class(TCustomSwitch, ILayoutBaseControl)
private
  FGroupID: integer;
  procedure SetGroupID(const Value: integer);
  function GetIBHeight: Single;
  function GetIBWidth: Single;
  procedure SetIBHeight(const Value: Single);
  procedure SetIBWidth(const Value: Single);
  procedure DoSwitchEvent(Sender: TObject);
public
  LayoutControlType: TLayoutControlType;
  property LFIBGroup_ID: integer read FGroupID write SetGroupID;
  property LFIBWidth: Single read GetIBWidth write SetIBWidth;
  property LFIBHeight: Single read GetIBHeight  write SetIBHeight;

  procedure WriteToStream(ms: TStream);
  procedure ReadFromStream(ms: TStream; NewWidth: Single = 1; NewHeight: Single = 1);

  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
end;
```

Instantiate code

```
ctrl := TLayoutSwitch.Create(Background);
ctrl.Parent := Background;
ctrl.BringToFront;
(ctrl as ILayoutBaseControl).ReadFromStream(ms, Background.Width/tmpW, Background.Height/tmpH);
```

Comment: By saying "even allow setting IsChecked at runtime"; is it read-only or is it not available at all?

Comment: 'IsChecked' is not read only for a TSwitch. Its definitely a read/write property.

Comment: And the availability of it when you code?

Comment: Maybe you could show your class structure and how you are instantiating it

Comment: As fasr as I can see IsChecked comes from the IIsChecked interface. I don't have a newish version of Delphi.

Comment: This has been reported and accepted as a bug with Embarcadero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class name `TLayoutSwitch` "misguides" `FMX` to search for a presenter named `LayoutSwitch-style` which of course doesn't exist in the framework. However, it is possible to change that name to the ordinary `Switch-style` in the `OnPresentationNameChoosing` event which is fired directly after the standard name construction.

Declare a `TPresenterNameChoosingEvent` procedure in your class, for example:

```
  procedure ChoosePresentationName(Sender: TObject; var PresenterName: string);
```

and assign this to the event in the constructor

```
constructor TLayoutSwitch.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  OnPresentationNameChoosing := ChoosePresentationName;
  ...
end;
```

Implementation could be as simple as

```
procedure TLayoutSwitch.ChoosePresentationName(Sender: TObject; var PresenterName: string);
begin
  PresenterName := 'Switch-style';
end;
```

The `Switch-style` presenter/presentation is the one used by `TSwitch`. Therefore it now looks and behaves the same.